# How to make the sliding transition working?

Tags: html, css

I have a card with contents. When the page is loaded, it only shows the card with a gradient overlay with a header. But when the card hovers, it will show a description text under the header and expands the gradient overlay. I tried to add a transition to make it slide from the bottom of the card, but it's not working.

Here's my HTML and CSS.

```css
.feature-card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: url('');
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.feature-card .feature-card-content {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 30px 10px 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(360deg, #000, transparent);
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.feature-card .feature-card-content .card-desc {
  height: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.feature-card:hover .feature-card-content .card-desc {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-md-12'>
  <div class='col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 feature-card'>
    <div class='feature-card-content'>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <div class='card-desc'>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make a smooth sliding transition of showing text when the card hovers.

Answer (score 2):

In this case parent element (`.feature-card-content`) does not have height, so the child (`.card-desc`) does not know how height 100% is.

Try use `max-height`.

```css
.feature-card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: url('');
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.feature-card .feature-card-content {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 30px 10px 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(360deg, #000, transparent);
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

.feature-card .feature-card-content .card-desc {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.feature-card:hover .feature-card-content .card-desc {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-md-12'>
  <div class='col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 feature-card'>
    <div class='feature-card-content'>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <div class='card-desc'>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```